# Add a separate tab for "on hold" questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, unanswered-questions

Normally I wait in the Newest tab and watch new questions stream in for me to potentially answer. However, especially in Code Review SE, the first page can be filled with questions that are `[on hold]` for a while (due to bad formatting/phrasing/lack of context) that the next unanswered question is already found on the second page.

Also, in most cases, questions that are `[on hold]` rarely get follow-up editing. Putting them together with the newest questions makes the Newest tab just cluttered with questions that aren't actionable.

It would be nice to either:

- Have a dedicated tab for `[on hold]` questions, or
- Have the "Unanswered" tab bechronological, or
- Have a "newest unanswered" tab, or
- Prefix `[on hold]` instead of putting it at the end, for easy spotting.

The point is to easily have access to unanswered questions if one just wants to answer questions, or access to `[on hold]` questions if one just needs to do some corrective commenting.

---

The unanswered tab is currently not chronological. It's probably designed that way to unearth really old, unattended questions. But a question that's a year old, with a user that probably has moved on, might not be a prime target for a regular responder.

Comment: "the unanswered tab is not chronological"...there are four ways to sort it, one of which is in chronological order ("newest").

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Not sure about that. If you've been to, say, Code Review SE's [unanswered section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15), the first few might seem chronological. But visit a few more pages and you'll see that some 2018 questions can be found in the second or third pages, and some 2015 ones come earlier.

Comment: Wow, 9 downvotes and only one person cared to explain (and at the same time answer in detail). Hmm...

Comment: Note that on meta sites, especially on feature requests, voting is used to indicate agreement or disagreement with the proposed feature, not necessarily to indicate the post's quality or usefulness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that it's up to the author to add in any requested details - their not doing so decreases their chances of getting a good answer. Sure, there are quite a lot of questions that can be easily edited to be on-topic by others (e.g. they have a clear question, but it's not that clear on first glance, which triggered a bad "unclear" closure, etc.) but the vast majority of questions by their very nature can only be edited into a reopenable state by their authors.

Also, with regards to comments, very likely, users will already have been left comments about their closure by others, and even if not, the close reason provides a good indication and links to the help center.

That said, this is already possible in search:

```
closed:1
```

...or to search for closed questions with no answers:

```
closed:1 answers:0
```

...or to exclude questions closed as duplicates from the search results (since those aren't marked "on hold" for 5 days):

```
closed:1 duplicate:0
```

You can sort the search results by "newest" to get them in chronological order.

Overall, I don't see the need for this tab, as is currently written in the question. You can use search to find these questions, and most of them can only be edited by their authors and have already been commented on by others, and even if not, the close reason provides a clear pointer.

Comment: Managed to get the list I wanted with `closed:0 answers:0` then viewing the newest. Thanks for the hint!